# Data structure to hold Excel column names with their values

Tags: java, data-structures, excel

I am learning how to read Excel workbooks in Java and want to know what a good Data Structure will be for holding Column names with the values under them.

**Example:**
[image: Excel Sheet]

I want to be able to call a method: `getColumnValue(String columnName, int indexOfValue)` and get the value at that position for the specified column name.

I was thinking of a Hash Table with Linked Lists. However, that seems like a lot of overhead as there can be any number of columns and values associated with them.

What would be a good recommendation for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't use a library? They already have all that a user may need to read an excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed you need a generic solution, where the program is not tied to a specific column structure at run time, you can use an  `ArrayList` of rows, where each row is a string array `String[]`. You will need an additional `HashTable<String,int>` to store the mapping of the column name to the column index (a `HashMap` will probably work, either). So if you have

```
 HashTable<String,int> columnMapping;
 ArrayList<String[]> tableValues;
```

you can implement `getColumnValue` by

```
 String getColumnValue(String columnName, int indexOfValue)
 {
     return tableValues.get(columnMapping.get(columnName))[indexOfValue];
 }
```

You may consider to add some error handling here, some code which determines the column names and some more code which reads the excel rows into the `String` arrays with one entry per column. If you need the values in a typed form, consider to replace the `String[]` rows by `Object[]` and store the cell content as objects of type `String`, `Integer`, `Double` or `Date`. You can also implement a speficic class `CellContent` and store your rows as `CellContent[]` arrays, if you have specific requirements and a need to implement specific behaviour or methods for a content element.

Note this is a rough scetch of a general purpose solution. One can modify this and create different variants, for more specific requirements.

If you need a *less* generic variant, because your program expects a specific column structure, best solution is probably to create a specific DTO class `MyRowType` for holding the specific values of a row, and use a variable like 
`ArrayList<MyRowType> tableValues` for storing the table content.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! This looks like how I want to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need performance, you probably need Arrays to hold column values, else 1. you will have memory overhead and 2. accessing lower rows will be slow.

Columns can be either a Hashmap (name -> Array) or directly Object fields (the latter one is preferable but requires fields and types to be statically known).

This would be the basic, column-based answer that assumes types in every column are the same, each column is often/always filled and represent the same data. If your data is more sparse, you can store by row, each row being one Hashmap (column name -> value) you can then store in an Array or a Hashmap.

Comment: Can you expand on the "Object fields" part? Do you mean each column is an object (making a class for each column) and having the fields inside those classes? Don't think I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: I meant, for a given excel file, you have a matching class. Here you would have a class MyExcel with fields `ArrayList<Integer> senders;ArrayList<Integer> receivers;` and so on. Apologies for not being exact on Java types.